# Page tries to render before data is loaded from API - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am pulling data from a cyrpto API that loads data of 250 coins. When I pull only 100 coins, the data is rendered fine. When I see it to 250, the data is rendered before loaded and it gives an error. The data is loaded in console when I log 250 coins.

The data function:

```
const fetchCoinData = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const fetchedCoinData = await getCoinsData();
    setData(fetchedCoinData);
    setLoading(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchCoinData();
  }, []);
```

The API call:

```
export const getCoinsData = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await Axios.get(
      `https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false&price_change_percentage=1h%2C24h%2C7d`
    );
    return response.data;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};
```

Comment: The page will always render before the API completes. This is why we check if `data` has length.

Comment: I am checking for that. `{loading || !data ? (<img className="loading-gif" src={Loading} alt="Loading.." />) : ( <Table />)`

Comment: It does wait for coins to load when the data is 100 entries. But when I increase it to 250 it gives the error

Comment: Please provide the error as well as relevant parts of your render function.

Comment: What is `data` being set to initially?

Comment: `const [data, setData] = useState(null);`
`useEffect(() => {
    fetchCoinData();
  }, []);`

Comment: Looks like your `setLoading(true)` is possibly triggering a rerender before the fetch completes. You could move the fetch to a use effect triggered by `loading` state change.

Comment: We definitely have to see the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you wrapped your axios response in a promise and change your state in the then function since it seems like your state is updating before your API call is over. Something like the followng would help.

```
await getCoinsData()
    .then(fetchedCoinData => {
        setData(fetchedCoinData))
        setLoading(false)
    });
```